# Creating multiple git tags

Tags: git, bash, tags

I am looping through a file that contains tags in the following format:

```
v10.0.20170216164446
v10.0.20170221122822
v10.0.20170221150333
v10.0.20170224112821
v10.0.20170224113321
v10.0.20170224114206
v10.0.20170224151512
v10.0.20170227181117
v10.0.20170227192857
v10.0.20170228160748
```

I am doing something as simple as:

```
while read p; do echo $p; git tag "$p"; done <../filename.txt
```

Ideally it should be creating all the tags as it parses them, but I get the following error:

```
v10.0.20170216164446
fatal: 'v10.0.20170216164446?' is not a valid tag name.
v10.0.20170221122822
fatal: 'v10.0.20170221122822?' is not a valid tag name.
v10.0.20170221150333
fatal: 'v10.0.20170221150333?' is not a valid tag name.
v10.0.20170224112821
fatal: 'v10.0.20170224112821?' is not a valid tag name.
```

I have no idea why it is adding a "?" after each tag. Any ideas on what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Is it possible that the file is untracked in git, thus adding the question mark to the end of the file name?

Comment: I am not checking in the file though. I just want to add the tags inside it.

Comment: The question mark is probably replacing an unprintable character, such as perhaps a carriage-return (^M or \r are various ways to express this that are printable or viewable). If so, removing them from the file you are reading, or stripping them out after reading them, would do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file in Notepad++, then go to `Edit>EOL Conversion>Unix (LF)`. That should do the trick.

What is happening, is that at the end of the file there is a carriage return `CR`. By converting it to Unix EOL conversions, it gets rid of it.

Comment: Thank you! I'm wondering if there is a straightforward way to see the line returns in sublime.

Comment: I don't think it natively supports it, correct me if I am wrong. I am sure there are plugins that enable you to see it though.

Comment: I am sure that there are plugins too.